# Алгоритм XAdES-T и его реализация

Tags: java, xml, безопасность, цифровая-подпись, signature

Доброго времени суток.

Прошу, подскажите как трактовать стандарт: http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101900_101999/101903/01.04.01_60/ts_101903v010401p.pdf

Интересует нода **SignatureTimeStamp**, а именно как она формируется. 
В стандарте написано (пункт 7.3):

> This property uses the implicit mechanism as the time-stamped data object is always the same. For building the input to
>   the digest computation, applications MUST:
>   1) **Take the ds:SignatureValue element and its contents.**
>   2) If the ds:Canonicalization element is present canonicalize it using the indicated algorithm. If not, use
>   the standard canonicalization method specified by XMLDSIG

То есть для вычисления **SignatureTimeStamp** (согласно тексту стандарта) берется элемент **SignatureValue** и его значение, а не только значение.

Собственно вопрос: Для вычисления **SignatureTimeStamp** используется вся нода **SignatureValue** со значением или только значение этой ноды?

Спасибо.

Comment: Не ужели никто? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно ответ будет следующим. Удалось установить, что **берется вся нода целиком**.

Рассмотрим реализацию DSS: https://github.com/arhs/sd-dss/blob/61f8b7124a5cecf214ef982c0112538a39c6a03a/apps/dss/core/dss-document/src/main/java/eu/europa/ec/markt/dss/validation102853/xades/XAdESSignature.java

```
public Element getSignatureValue() {
    return DSSXMLUtils.getElement(signatureElement, xPathQueryHolder.XPATH_SIGNATURE_VALUE);
}
```

Далее рассмотрим метод `getElement()` класса `DSSXMLUtils`:

```
/**
* Return the Element corresponding to the XPath query.
*
* @param xmlNode     The node where the search should be performed.
* @param xPathString XPath query string
* @return
*/
public static Element getElement(final Node xmlNode, final String xPathString) {

    return (Element) getNode(xmlNode, xPathString);
}
```

Ну и метод `getNode()`:

```
/**
* Return the Node corresponding to the XPath query.
*
* @param xmlNode     The node where the search should be performed.
* @param xPathString XPath query string
* @return
*/
public static Node getNode(final Node xmlNode, final String xPathString) {

final NodeList list = getNodeList(xmlNode, xPathString);
    if (list.getLength() > 1) {
        throw new DSSException("More than one result for XPath: " + xPathString);
    }
    return list.item(0);
}
```